# Deployment failed-CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-code-deploy

I was able to successfully deploy code to ec2 instance yesterday, suddenly it is showing weird error while deploying today.

ERROR:

```
  The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances   failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems. (Error code: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS)
```

Then I found the problem in log files in the ec2 instance it says like below

```
 "InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Missing credentials - please check if this instance was started with an IAM instance profile"
```

So I checked if my ec2 instance actually assuming roles properly by doing like below

```
 curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/CodeDeployInstanceRole
```

it shows below output

```
 {
 "Code" : "AssumeRoleUnauthorizedAccess",
 "Message" : "EC2 cannot assume the role CodeDeployInstanceRole. Please see documentation at http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/RolesTroubleshooting.html.",
 "LastUpdated" : "2017-01-27T06:23:24Z"

 }
```

I made two instance roles CodeDeployInstance Role(AmazonEC2RoleforAWSCodeDeploy policy) and CodeDeployServiceRole( AWSCodeDeployRole policy) which are properly set.I added instance role to the ec2 instance while launching. But not sure why my ec2 instance not able to assume instance role.

Answer (score 0):

For instance profile IAM role, you want to make sure in the trust relationship it's trusting the ec2 endpoint. Someone might accidentally delete that trust relationship.